# Getting months as 01,02 instead of 1,2

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am working with the Calender class and more specifically I need to get back all 12 months as two numbers.

If I use the following code:

```
 int month = (myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)) +1;
```

This is what I get for the different months: 
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

But what I really need is:
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12

This is beacuse I need to make substrings and it will go wrong if the number of ints I get.
Is there an easy way to fix this?

I could use an if statement and check if the whole date is just 5 numbers, then add a zero and the 3 position, but it feels cumberstone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is loading as "1" instead of "01" is because it is stored in an `int`, do the following `if` statement:

```
String sMonth = "";
if (month < 10) {
    sMonth = "0"+String.valueOf(month);
} else {
    sMonth = String.valueOf(month);
}
```

Then use `sMonth` instead of `month`.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to try if statement try this

```
Date date = new Date();
String monthDateFormat = "MM";
SimpleDateFormat mdf = new SimpleDateFormat(monthDateFormat);
String month = mdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want it as an integer, you won't get leading zeros.  Assign a string variable as below

`String monthStr = month < 10 ? "0"+month : String.valueOf(month);`